# How to stop my discord bot remember data from another server

Tags: discord.py, replit

Hi I'm making a discord bot on [REPL](https://replit.com) (Python) and ran into a issue with the code remembering data across server. This is an issue for me because if I want to use this bot across server it will have setting from another server

Here is the link to the code: https://github.com/bosco26/BOTSCO-Bot.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replit has a inbuilt database! here's the link to the database docs: https://docs.replit.com/misc/database